# JOOQ multiset throwing syntax exception

Tags: mysql, sql, jooq

Recently moved to JOOQ `3.15.5` and tried the `Multiset` feature but it is throwing `SQLSyntaxErrorException`. Below is the query I wrote:

```
dslContext.select(
    tableA.asterisk(),
    multiset(
            select(tableB.DELETED, tableB.VALUE)
                .from(tableB)
                .where(tableB.ORDER_ID.eq(tableA.ORDER_ID))
    ).as("bookingAdditions")
).from(tableA)
 .where(tableA.BATCH_ID.greaterThan(batchId))
 .fetchInto(BookingDto.class);
```

Here is the relations:

```
|tableA|  1           n  |tableB| 
|      | --------------> |      | 
|      |                 |      | 
--------                  --------
(tableA)                  (tableB)
```

Here is the query that is being generated by JOOQ:

```
set @t = @@group_concat_max_len; set @@group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; select `tablea`.*, (select coalesce(json_merge_preserve('[]', concat('[', group_concat(json_array(`v0`, `v1`) separator ','), ']')), json_array()) from (select `tableb`.`deleted` as `v0`, `tableb`.`value` as `v1` from `db_name`.`booking_additions` as `tableb` where `tableb`.`order_id` = `tablea`.`order_id`) as `t`) as `bookingadditions` from `db_name`.`booking` as `tablea` where `tablea`.`batch_id` > 0; set @@group_concat_max_len = @t;
```

Here are exceptions:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [set @t = @@group_concat_max_len; set @@group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; select `tablea`.*, (select coalesce(json_merge_preserve('[]', concat('[', group_concat(json_array(`v0`, `v1`) separator ','), ']')), json_array()) from (select `tableb`.`deleted` as `v0`, `tableb`.`value` as `v1` from `db_name`.`booking_additions` as `tableb` where `tableb`.`order_id` = `tablea`.`order_id`) as `t`) as `bookingadditions` from `db_name`.`booking` as `tablea` where `tablea`.`batch_id` > ?; set @@group_concat_max_len = @t;]; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @@group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; select `tablea`.*, (select coalesce(jso' at line 1
    at org.jooq_3.15.5.MYSQL.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2988)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:639)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:349)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:295)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazyNonAutoClosing(AbstractResultQuery.java:316)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetchLazyNonAutoClosing(SelectImpl.java:2866)
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.collect(ResultQueryTrait.java:357)
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.fetchInto(ResultQueryTrait.java:1423)
    at com.company.BookingDAO.fetchBookings(BookingDAO.java:118)
    at
```

I am using `Mysql: 5.7`. What am I doing wrong? Any hint?

Comment: Are you using the commercial version of jOOQ because MySQL 5.7 is not supported in the free version. Only the newest version is supported (8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ generates three SQL statements separated by semicolons when you use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in a query. Unfortunately, the default behavior of MySQL is to disallow multiple queries in a single request.

You have to change your JDBC connection options to include `allowMultiQueries`.

Read more about it here: https://blog.jooq.org/mysqls-allowmultiqueries-flag-with-jdbc-and-jooq/

Answer (score 2):

#### Regarding the multiple statements

In addition to what [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70352656/521799) said, you could also specify the `Settings.renderGroupConcatMaxLenSessionVariable` to be `false` and increase your server's `@@group_concat_max_len` variable for your session or your server yourself.

jOOQ's default here is to assume it's easier to add the JDBC connection flag rather than change the server settings, but both approaches are viable.

#### Regarding correlated derived tables

This particular emulation requires support for correlated derived tables, which MySQL 5.7 doesn't support, see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12045. You're not going to get a correlated `MULTISET` expression to work on MySQL 5.7, but you could write an almost equivalent [`MULTISET_AGG`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/multiset-agg-function/) expression, like this:

```java
dslContext.select(
    tableA.asterisk(),
    multisetAgg(tableB.DELETED, tableB.VALUE).as("bookingAdditions")
).from(tableA)
 .join(tableB).on(tableB.ORDER_ID.eq(tableA.ORDER_ID))
 .where(tableA.BATCH_ID.greaterThan(batchId))
 // You can group by the primary key, or tableA.fields() if you don't have a PK
 .groupBy(tableA.ID)
 .fetchInto(BookingDto.class);
```

Unlike `MULTISET`, `MULTISET_AGG` produces `NULL` values instead of empty lists in case you're left joining `tableB`, as is usual for SQL aggregate functions. You could then use `coalesce(multisetAgg(...), multiset(...))` as a workaround.