# jooq jsonArrayAgg query mariadb/mysql always get "an error in your SQL syntax" exception

Tags: java, mariadb, jooq

If my SQL statement has the jsonArrayAgg command, jOOQ always raises an error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near".

However, when I turn on "general_log" in MariaDB and copy/post the jooq generate SQL statement to query the database, everything is fine, and the result is what I want.

My code simply like

```
     list = ctx.select(
                MAIN.KEYID,
                field(
                select(jsonArrayAgg(
                    jsonObject(
                        key("id").value(CONNECTOR.ID),
                        key("standard").value(CONNECTOR.STANDARD)
                ))).from(CONNECTOR)
                .where(CONNECTOR.MAINKEYID.eq(MAIN.KEYID))).as("connectors")                                
            ).from(MAIN)           
            .fetchInto(JSON_POJO.class);
```

jooq log

```
at org.jooq_3.15.12.MARIADB.debug(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2997) ~[jooq-3.15.12.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:639) ~[jooq-3.15.12.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:354) ~[jooq-3.15.12.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:295) ~[jooq-3.15.12.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazyNonAutoClosing(AbstractResultQuery.java:316) ~[jooq-3.15.12.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetchLazyNonAutoClosing(SelectImpl.java:2866) ~[jooq-3.15.12.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.collect(ResultQueryTrait.java:357) ~[jooq-3.15.12.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.fetchInto(ResultQueryTrait.java:1423) ~[jooq-3.15.12.jar:?]
```

jooq generate sql code simply like this

```
set @t = @@group_concat_max_len; set @@group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; 
select `mydb`.`main`.`keyid`, 
(select json_merge_preserve('[]', concat('[', group_concat(json_merge_preserve('{}', json_object('id', `mydb`.`Connector`.`id`), json_object('standard', `mydb`.`Connector`.`standard`)) separator ','), ']')) 
from `mydb`.`Connector` where `mydb`.`Connector`.`mainKeyid` = `mydb`.`main`.`keyid`) as `connectors` from `mydb`.`main`; 
set @@group_concat_max_len = @t
```

I have try jooq version from 3.12 ~ 3.16,

MariaDB 10.3 and upgrade to 10.11,

Java 11.0.18

[allowMultiQueries = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351547/jooq-multiset-throwing-syntax-exception)

but none of them worked.
How can I overcome this problem or find a workaround?

Comment: very sad that jOOQ isn't just using json_arrayagg.  are you certain that is the complete error message?   does it work if you disable the @@group_concat_max_len stuff? (see https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-group-concat/)

Comment: Yes,that is all error message,and I have set group_concat_max_len in my.cnf

Comment: yes, but jooq doesn't know you have set group_concat_max_len, so it is trying to temporarily set it for the select.  set the withRenderGroupConcatMaxLenSessionVariable setting to false so it doesn't try to do that, and verify the generated sql is just a select statement, and see if that resolves the problem.  if it does, allowMultiQueries wasn't being effective for some reason.

Comment: It's working when I set withRenderGroupConcatMaxLenSessionVariable  to false, you saved my day!
but I still don't realize what problem is. 
my jooq maven config is like 
<jdbcUrl>jdbc:mysql://${db.ip}:${db.port}/${db.schema}?useSSL=true&amp;allowMultiQueries=true</jdbcUrl>

Comment: @ysth: There was a time when jOOQ couldn't just use `JSON_ARRAYAGG`: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12169. May be worth reviewing. But these things don't lead to any issues in jOOQ's integration tests

Comment: @ysth: I just tried generating `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` calls again from jOOQ's internals (assuming neither `FILTER` nor `ABSENT ON NULL` clauses are used. Still no success, found yet another bug: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31159. MariaDB's JSON support has been bug ridden for many years now, which is why jOOQ works around things in such cumbersome ways.